# Cannot load play.http.errorHandler

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm using Play in Scala to develop a website. I've added the following line to my `application.conf` file in order to include the default error handling:

```
play.http.errorHandler = play.api.http.HtmlOrJsonHttpErrorHandler
```

I've done this by advice of the [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaErrorHandling). However, when I add this line I get the following error:

```
play.api.PlayException: Cannot load play.http.errorHandler[play.http.errorHandler [play.api.http.HtmlOrJsonHttpErrorHandler] was not loaded.]
at play.utils.Reflect$.loadClass$1(Reflect.scala:111)
at play.utils.Reflect$.configuredClass(Reflect.scala:124)
at play.utils.Reflect$.bindingsFromConfiguration(Reflect.scala:50)
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler$.bindingsFromConfiguration(HttpErrorHandler.scala:54)
at play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.$anonfun$new$2(BuiltinModule.scala:85)
at play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.$anonfun$new$1(BuiltinModule.scala:35)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:29)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.http.HtmlOrJsonHttpErrorHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at play.utils.Reflect$.loadClass$1(Reflect.scala:105)
    at play.utils.Reflect$.configuredClass(Reflect.scala:124)
    at play.utils.Reflect$.bindingsFromConfiguration(Reflect.scala:50)
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler$.bindingsFromConfiguration(HttpErrorHandler.scala:54)
    at play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.$anonfun$new$2(BuiltinModule.scala:85)
    at play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.$anonfun$new$1(BuiltinModule.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:241)
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get when I go to localhost: [image]

Any idea why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: `HtmlOrJsonHttpErrorHandler` is available starting Play 2.7. Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: Where can I easily see this? I tfound this in the build.sbt file ```version = 2.6.x```.

Comment: I've also found this link: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaErrorHandling which is an earlier version and there they use a default error handler as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Comparing changes](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/compare/2.6.25...2.7.0) between Play 2.6.25 and 2.7.0 we deduce that `HtmlOrJsonHttpErrorHandler` was introduced by [Add an HttpErrorHandler that selects the client's preferred media type #8540](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/8540). The version of Play used in your project should be specified under `project/plugins.sbt` as something like

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.0")
```

If you are using 2.6.0 then follow the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration27) to 2.7.

Comment: Are u sure the problem lays with ```HtmlOrJsonHttpErrorHandler``` and not with  ```play.http.errorHandler```? To my understanding, this line should work in Play 2.6 ```play.http.errorHandler = DefaultHttpErrorHandler```, however, it returns the same error.

Comment: I have ```addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.19")``` by the way, I just verified. If I can just find a way to introduce some default error handing using this version I think that would be better than migrating to 2.7.

Comment: @Arno You have to provide fully qualified name to error handler `play.http.errorHandler = play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler`.